# ActionCall in Xamarin Android parsing not working

Tags: android, parsing, xamarin, textview

I have an Adapter with rows from View, and each row contains some information. I am trying to make a Actioncall, so if someone clicks the row with the phone number, then it starts dialing. This work but the problem is I don't get the phone number from the TextView, I get a random number.

**This is the code**

The function for when the users clicks on the phone number

```
  private void TelSelected(TextView obj)
        {
            mTelefonNumar = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3);
            Toast.MakeText(this, mTelefonNumar.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
            string stringtelefon = mTelefonNumar.ToString();
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:" + stringtelefon);
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall, uri);
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
```

The Toast returns this android.widget.TextView{2e4a768b V.ED..C...... 0, 198-698,264 #7f0b0055 app:id/textView3}

And the Intent.ActionCall, calls this number 247 680 but the number another one/

```
 public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View row = convertView;

            if (row == null)
            {
                row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(mLayout, parent, false);
            }


            row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3).Text = Linfo[position].TelClient;

            row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3).Click += InformatiiListAdapter_Click;

            return row;
        }

        void InformatiiListAdapter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //He clicked on the Telephone Number
            mNrApasat.Invoke((TextView)sender);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

.ToString() on a TextView will show information about the View, not the text it displays. The following would fix it :

```
((TextView)sender).Text;
```

instead of

```
((TextView)sender).ToString();
```

An cleaner way (because the displayed text might not always be exactly a usable phone number) would be to store the number in the row 'tag' property (in which you can store anything).
And to set the event on the row.

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;

    if (row == null)
    {
        row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(mLayout, parent, false);
    }

    row.SetTag(Linfo[position].TelClient);
    row.Click += InformatiiListAdapter_Click;
    row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3).Text = (string)row.GetTag();

    return row;
}

void InformatiiListAdapter_Click(object row, EventArgs e)
{
    //He clicked on the Telephone Number
    string phoneNumber = (string)(((View)row).GetTag());
    // do stuff with the phone number
}
```

also, on a side note, FindViewByID is very expensive processing-wise, avoid doing it too much, you might want to look into the ViewHolder pattern, it'll make scrolling smoother

also, it would be better to set the item click listener on the list itself, instead of registering an event on each convertView.

Comment: I get an error when I am trying your line mNrApasat.Invoke(((TextView)sender).Text); - Delegate 'System.Action<Android.Widget.TextView>' has some invalid arguments.     The type of mNrApasat is Action<TextView>

Comment: yeah you never told what mNrApasat was. but you probably don't need it anymore, ((View)row).GetTag() is a the phone number string, so you would just pass it to another method doing the phone call or something